# installing ubuntu 14.04 in win 7 lost partition

Tags: 14.04

today i installed ubuntu 14.04LTS on windows 7 then in ubuntu , win 7 partition didnt appear. it shows whole drive  3.1gb used and 147. gb free
how to recover win 7 partition and uninstall ubuntu and win 7 back

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? Using Wubi? LiveCD?. What do you mean by "On Windows 7 then in Ubuntu".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you selected "Replace Windows 7"
 when installing Ubuntu, there unfortunatly is no way to recover your Windows 7 partition, because it has been formated and overwritten by Ubuntu.

Comment: i dint select Replace Windows 7

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu using a Live CD or using wubi while running windows? Try installing gparted in Ubuntu and check what partitions are on your hard drive

Comment: thanx for ur reply
my com had 3 drives c, d and e
in drive d and e is data deleted or not?

Comment: i installed ubuntu using live usb

Comment: Do you have multiple hard drives or just one with three partitions? Could you post a screenshot of gparted?

Comment: i have one hard drive with 3 partitions
i cant download gparted because of slow net .
what is size of gparted?

Comment: gparted itself is about 512kB, but there might be dependencies that also need to be downloaded

Comment: i saw gparted size on sourceforge  its 200mb not possible for download now may be tomorrow any other option or how to recover data on drive d and e
sorry for late reply i m using it from mobile

Comment: What you saw on sourceforge was a bootable live iso image with gparted installed. But you don't need to download the whole iso, just the program itself since you already have the operating system. Just open a terminal and type in `sudo apt-get install gparted` and it will install only the program and the needed dependencies, which shouldn't be more than 5MB

Comment: i did this but it says 
reading package lists ... done
reading state information...done
E: unable to locate package gparted

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` and then running `sudo apt-get install gparted` again.

Comment: it taking too much time should i downld gparted-0.19.1.tar.bz2 file on sourcefroge

Comment: You could try that, or just use the live usb stick you already have, its preinstalled there.

Comment: this is 2mb file download complete. how to installed this file?

Comment: `tar xvf gparted-0.19.1.tar.bz2` to extract it. Then `cd gparted-0.19.1`. This way, you need to build it for yourself. `./configure`, `make` and `make install` should compile gparted. Then run it with `sudo gparted`

Comment: i didnt understand what u say bu i did this open with archive manager then it becomes 10.8 mb file then i extract and in extractes folder click on INSTALL with green icon then new windoe appear then save current file
and then type in terminal  sudo apt-get
install gparted  
the it shows gparted is already the newest version

Comment: Fine, so it was already installed :D please launch it using sudo gparted or by searching for it in unity. Then, take a screenshot of the window when it's done loading and upload it to imgur.com. Then post the link as a comment.

Comment: screenshot http://imgur.com/YAhnHLO

Comment: I have some bad news for you: your windows partition isn't there anymore and has been overwritten by Ubuntu. And, as I said in my answer, there is no way to recover it. Sorry :(

Comment: had i lost  data while it on drive D and E in windows 7

Comment: As gparted tells you, there are only 2 partitions on your hard drive: one ext4 which is for the Ubuntu filesystem and one swap partition which is for Ubuntus memory. There are no other f.e. NTFS or FAT32 partitions on the drive and because you said you only have one hard drive, yes, you lost all data on C, D, and E. Again, sorry for that :(

Comment: thank you for ur help.
i saw testdisk 
cant it recover?

Comment: No. If you format a partition (or a drive), data can't be recovered. You could search for a local hard drive recovery professional, he might be able to recover at least parts of the data.

Comment: after installing ubuntu
i tried to install windows 7 from live use and in booting

this appeared

                    windows boot manager
Windows failed  to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the case.to fix the problem:

   
If you do not have this disc, contact your administrator or computer manufacture for assistance.

   File:  \Boot\BCD
   Status:Oxc0000098

Info :The windows boot configuration data does not contain a valid OS entry.

screenshot link  http://imgur.com/ikuiiKF

how to install windows 7